# How to use Python to pick up texts on PDF documents

Tags: python, pdf, extract

I have tons of commercial invoices to work with, in PDF format. Some information such the billing party, transaction occurred date and amount of money are needed to be picked.

In another word, I need to copy these information from each commercial invoice and paste them into an Excel spreadsheet.

These information are all at the same position on the PDF document, always the same place on each PDF.

Is there a way that I can have Python to pick up the information and store them into Excel spreadsheet, instead of manually copy&paste?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to read the pdf file you can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

```
from StringIO import StringIO


pdfContent = StringIO(getPDFContent("Billineg.pdf").encode("ascii", "ignore"))
for line in pdfContent:
    print line
```

---

other option you can use [pypdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html)

small example

```
from pyPdf import  PdfFileReader    
input1 = PdfFileReader(file("Billineg.pdf", "rb"))    
# print the title of document1.pdf
print "title = %s" % (input1.getDocumentInfo().title)
```

after extracting data you can write them into [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)  or for excel you can use [`xlwt`](http://www.python-excel.org/)

getpdf content is method

```
import pyPdf  
def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    num_pages = 10
    p = file(path, "rb")
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(p)
    for i in range(0, num_pages):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())     
    return content
```

Comment: thanks sundar nataraj Сундар, for the first one, it gives error "NameError: name 'getPDFContent' is not defined". could you please help again?

Comment: @MarkK please check now

Comment: nataraj Сундар, it works. the last 2 lines in 'getPDFContent', under 'for' shall be indented. thank you.

Comment: `print "title = %s" % (input1.getDocumentInfo().title)` gives me `title = untitled`